# Vibration in 2012 Opel Combo Cosmo CDTI at speed

Tags: engine, vibration

I have read many related questions and answers here, but it looks like my question is still different, because in my case the vibration occurs only when I push on the accelerator pedal. That is, noticeable high-frequency vibrations happen at the speeds of 120-130 km/h (about 75-80 mph) when I push on the accelerator pedal. Which prompts me to think that the vibrations are not because of the tires, but probably because of the engine. The vibrations are mainly felt in the steering wheel, by I think they are also felt in the seat, and probably go throughout the vehicle to some degree. There is also a vibration-like background tune seemingly coming from under the hood when I step on the accelerator at high speeds. If I go faster, the vibration also increases. But, at whatever speed, once I release the accelerator, the vibration disappears immediately.

I bought a used car today to replace my car that was damaged by a massive hail, didn't see this issue at test drive, because I didn't go on the highway (my current experience shows it is always a good idea to test-drive vehicles on a highway at high speeds).

Has anyone experienced anything like this before, and does anyone know how to fix this? Could this be a failing engine or an improperly mounted engine? The car is under a 3-month engine and transmission warranty.

Comment: You say vibration, is it small vibrations or more of a shaking?

Comment: @BriHan Those were small vibrations, but it appears that after balancing the tires the vibrations went away.